# Real analysis question about limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $0  < x < 1$, show that $x^n → 0$ as $n → ∞$ .

I'm thinking it has something to do with rational numbers (declaring $x = p/q$) and then using exponent laws to show that $x^n = p^n/q^n$, and since $q > p$ ... but I'm not sure where to go with this.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is monotone decreasing, since $x < 1$ and hence $$x^{n+1} = x \cdot x^{n} < x^n$$

and it is bounded below by $0$, since $x > 0$ and hence $$\underbrace{x \cdot x \cdots x}_{\text{ $n$ times }} > 0$$ for every $n$.

Therefore, we know that the sequence converges to some limit $0 \le \gamma \le x$.

We must have  $$\gamma = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^{n+1} = x \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^n = x \gamma$$

And since $0 < x < 1$ we know that $\gamma = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x \in (0,1)$, we have $x=\dfrac1{1+M}$, where $M>0$. By binomial theorem, we now have
$$x^n = \dfrac1{(1+M)^n} < \dfrac1{1+nM}$$
Use this to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$0<x<1\implies x>x^2>x^3>\ldots >x^n\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N$$

$$a_n>0\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{a_n}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the natural log : you want to show, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ with $x^n < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$ . Then, from: $$ x^n <\epsilon$$, apply $ln$ on both sides (using the fact that $ln$ is monotone increasing, so that if $0<a<b$ , then $lna<lnb$), so that $x^n <\epsilon$ then $lnx^n <ln\epsilon$....

EDIT: Maybe a more fundamental fact is this: a monotone bounded sequence converges to its (least upper, or greatest-lower ) bound. We can show $x^n$ is monotone decreasing in $(0,1)$ ( as a function of $n$ , i.e., for fixed $x$): $x^{n+1}-x^n=x^n(x-1)$, which is negative in $(0,1)$ (since $x^n$ is positive in $(0,1)$ ).Using that $x^n>0$ in $(0,1)$  we have that $x^n$ is monotone and bounded, so it must converge to its least upper bound. Then you can use the $ln$ to show this GLB is $0$

Comment: @Deven Ware, right, just edited it, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11841/discussion-between-danul-g-and-user99680)